# C program prints out wrong values

Tags: c

I made a simple code to scan for user input and print it out.
It only outputs the first character if its a string an gives me wrong values if its integers. The code is written in C. I'm using codeblocks on ubuntu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   char name;
    int age;
    printf("Enter your name: \n");
    scanf("%c", &name);
    printf("Enter your age: \n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Your name is %c and your age is %d", &name, &age);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%c` is placeholder for a character. Try `%s` for strings

Comment: What does &name mean? Think about why you are using &name, &age in the scanf function. Then think about why you absolutely should NOT use &name, &age in the printf function. Turn warnings on in the compiler and it will tell you.

Answer (score 2):

you declared `name` as `char`, that can hold only 1 character,  generally any name is more than 1 character, so what you need is an array `char name[50]`, and use `%s` for reading it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   char name[50] = {0};
    int age;
    printf("Enter your name: \n");
    scanf("%49s", name);
    printf("Enter your age: \n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Your name is %s and your age is %d", name, age);
    return 0;
}
```

`&` prints the address of the variables, you just need to use only variable names in `printf`

Collect the return value of `scanf` to check correct number of items are read

Comment: `scanf("%s", name)` may overflow the `name` buffer. Use the "m" modifier. Change `name` to `char *name=NULL` and use `scanf("%ms", &name)`. This will allocate enough  space to store the actual string read, without a potential buffer overflow.

Comment: It should be `%49s`, because of the null terminator

Comment: @koder `"%ms"` is a useful idea except it is not part of the standard C library.